# Formatting bar change - split code button into input, code and output buttons

Tags: feature-request

Could there be **buttons** in the formatting tools for "input" and "output" as well as "code"?

- It would get people to think about inputs and outputs when posting code-lessening the need for "Some input required" comments.
- It would allow for more machine searchable code as well as inputs and outputs.

It could be a dropdown menu from "{}" to be uncluttered.

Comment: Just insert a `<!-- language: none -->` before the output block to disable highlighting.

Comment: I'm not asking to quote something.  I'm asking for buttons on the interface. @TinyGiant

Comment: If I was getting a machine to read stack overflow code.  What would I look for for input?  then what would I look for for output? @TinyGiant

Comment: The consensus is to format input and output as code and use the `<!-- language: none -->` prettify hint to disable syntax highlighting. Being that it should be formatted as code, you should use the code button on the formatting bar. There is no reason for another button (or two). If you're thinking of trying to get a machine to read Stack Overflow questions and answers consistently, you're going to have an insanely difficult task on your hands.

Comment: When you have "<!-- language: none -->" everything looks like a nail.  I disagree that this is a duplicate.   I saw that question and the answer was inadequate.

Comment: That is the correct answer whether you like it or not.